# Copy file from USB drive to a desktop loaded via a LiveCD

Tags: files, permissions, root, cp

I have booted my computer using a LiveCD and want to copy a file from a USB drive to the LiveCD loaded desktop.

I want to copy a file from the USB drive to the desktop environment in memory, which has been loaded by the LiveCD. I do not want to copy a file onto the actual LiveCD itself.

I appreciate the copied file will disappear, when the OS loaded via the LiveCD has been switched off.

I have tried the following:

```
sudo cp "/location_of_usb_file/file.dat" "location_on_live_cd_environment_folder"
```

But I get the following error:

```
cp: cannot stat 'file.dat': Permission denied
```

If I do:

```
ls -l
```

I get :

```
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 65546 May 30 12:00 file.dat
```

How do I copy the file?

Comment: What about the permission for `"location_on_live_cd_environment_folder"`???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the internal workings of [FUSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace)¹, it can happen with FUSE filesystems that root cannot access a file, even though some other user could. In such cases, you can change to the owning user to access the file. For example:

```
sudo -u ubuntu cat "/location_of_usb_file/file.dat" |
sudo tee "location_on_live_cd_environment_folder"
```

¹  <sub>More of a bug than a feature, really, but one that is apparently hard to fix.</sub>